# Moving camera in large view

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d

In my cocos2d app I was wondering how to make a CCSprite move on the screen but have the screen focused on the CCSprite, so when the sprite moves the view moves with the CCSprite. Is there a tutorial to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a `CCFollow` action in cocos2d for this purpose. Usage is simple:

```
[myLayer runAction: [CCFollow actionWithTarget: heroSprite]];
```

For more information, have a look at the [API docs](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_follow.html).

Answer (score 0):

For making such games you need to create some layers and then move the layers. Just like in a 2D side scrolling game the background layer moves(or changes) and only the y coordinate of the character is changed so that the character appears to be moving.

For such game you can refer to this post ---

http://johnehartzog.com/2009/10/2d-scrolling-game-with-cocos2d-tilemap-with-zoom/

and to find additional codes for the same you can check out the code snippet and the end of this page.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/5363

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason, you wanted to manually make a camera system, the way to do it would be to set a camera x and y based on the position of the sprite you're trying to follow, and then draw everything at its normal position minus the camera x and y values.